# How to bend an object with SimpleDeform without stretching it?

Tags: modeling

Hi could someone please help me to find a way to bend an object without stretching it? Should i use rigging?
[image]

as you can see when i try to bend this Object (Strap) it stretches the whole model.

Comment: You haven't said how you are actually trying to bend it? In any case, did you apply the Scale to it (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) before trying to bend it?

Comment: i am very sorry to disappoint you, but if an object has thickness, you cannot bend it without stretching it. This is in our world mathematically not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Object* mode, right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry* so that the origin stick to the geometry, otherwise it will deform the shape, see how it deforms if I move the mesh away from the origin:

[image]